# Qgridlayout rowspan with qlabel text over several columns

Tags: qt, qlabel, qgridlayout

I would like to achieve the following structure

```
--------------------
|text text| BUTTON |
|text text----------       
|text text text text| 
|text text text text|
---------------------
```

Where all that text is contained in a QLabel. I was trying to achieve this through the use of the rowspan property of a QGridLayout

```
QGridLayout *title_layout = new QGridLayout;
title_layout->addWidget(title_label, 0,0,3,1);
title_layout->addWidget(star_button,0,1,1,1,Qt::AlignRight);
```

in which i stated that the button could only occupy one row, but the label can occupy 3. The problem is that the text is anyway presented like this:

```
--------------------
|text text| BUTTON |
|text text|        |
|text text|        | 
|text text|        |
---------------------
```

Is there any way to achieve the first layout?

Comment: The main problem is that what you want can not be, widgets can only have rectangular structure, the QLabel will never have the shape you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I f you want put that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, widgets can have a rectangular structure within a layout.